# Unity: How to adjust size of sliced sprite with a transition?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, sprite

I am trying to animate a sliced sprite's height size. Where am I going wrong with my code?

[Sprite Renderer component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOeYK.png)

I can transform Game Objects easily enough (position, scale etc), but applying the same steps doesn't seem to work for the Sprite Renderer component.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class localSpriteSlice : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer spriteSliceSize;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //increase height of sprite and retain slice proportions
        spriteSliceSize.bounds.size.y += 0.1F;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to increase the height of the sprite, but it throws a "Cannot modify the return value of 'Bounds.size' because it is not a variable."

Comment: My guess is you should use spriterenderer.size. or just have a look at what bound is. it's basically a rectangle covering the object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Grey_Rhino. I had to make the variable public and added a Vector2 to size, but it works now:

```
public class localSpriteSlice : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer spriteSliceSize;

    void Update()
    {
        //increase height of sprite and retain slice proportions
        spriteSliceSize.size += new Vector2(0, 0.1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't necessarily have to make it `public`. In order to reference it via the Inspector rather use `[SerializeField] private ...` it is cleaner regarding to capsulation. **or** in your `Start` or `Awake` method use `spriteSliceSize = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()` in order to get the reference on runtime